# Optimus headless browser with C#

Tags: c#, optimus

Can somebody tell me how to use Optimus (headless browser) nuget package with C# to get response from a URL.  I also want javascript on the page to be executed automatically like phantomjs.

Comment: did you try the [project's example code](https://bitbucket.org/RusKnyaz/optimus/wiki/Home) ?

Comment: yes I did try that but example code is very much basic.  I want a more detailed example.

Comment: Indeed Optimus documentation is really short. It's hard to find out how to use it

Comment: Your question is too general. How to open the URL is in the example. What exactly do you want to do? Which details do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Quite a simple bit of kit:

1. Create an Engine component first (common for dynamic and static pages):

   `Engine engine = new Engine();`
2. Open the url of the html document you want to retreive:

   a) Not waiting for any elements added in with javascript:

   `engine.OpenUrl("http://google.com").Wait();`

   b) Waiting for any elements added in with javascript:

   `engine.OpenUrl("http://google.com")`

   and then either:

   - `engine.WaitDesappearingOfId("some-id")`
   - `engine.WaitId("some-id")`
   - `engine.WaitDocumentLoad()`
   - `engine.WaitSelector("#some-id")`
   - `engine.WaitSelector(".some-class")`

now you open the url, there are two ways of doing this - 
load the document (prior to any javascript being executed):

More complete examples:

```
public static string dynamicLoadingPage()
{
    var engine = new Engine();
    engine.OpenUrl("https://html5test.com");
    var tagWithValue = engine.WaitSelector("#score strong").FirstOrDefault();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Score: " + tagWithValue.InnerHTML);
}
```

Otherwise:

```
static string staticLoadingPage()
{
   var engine = new Engine();
   engine.OpenUrl("http://google.com").Wait();
   Console.WriteLine("The first document child node is: " + engine.Document.FirstChild);
   Console.WriteLine("The first document body child node is: " + engine.Document.Body.FirstChild);
   Console.WriteLine("The first element tag name is: " + engine.Document.ChildNodes.OfType<HtmlElement>().First().TagName);
   Console.WriteLine("Whole document innerHTML length is: " + engine.Document.DocumentElement.InnerHTML.Length);

}
```

Comment: How do you get the HTTP status code of the request? Would be ideal to verify the page loaded correctly before attempting to access dom elements

Comment: I've managed to get the page loaded but fail to find any documentation on how to interact with the page, e.g. click an anchor that I've got using `QuerySelectorAll.Single()` - it just gives me something of type `IElement` but there's nothing clickable there, as far I can see.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add - I need to atually **click** the button, not only read the *href* and navigate to it. The JS executed with the clicks adds something to the session/headers making a simple navigation not work out.